# PHP: Can't combine string with variable to get another variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to combine a string with variable to get needed variable. This is the code that I think should be fine:

```
$desc1 = 123;
$desc2 = "asdf";
$desc3 = "asdf123";
for($i = 1; $i<= 3; $i++)
{
    echo 
    "
        <p>$desc".$i."</p>
    ";
}
```

It should print me:

123

asdf

asdf123

Instead it just prints me:

1

2

3

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work and solve your issue ;)

```
    $desc[1] = 123;
    $desc[2] = 'asdf';
    $desc[3] = 'asdf123';
    for($i = 1; $i<= 3; $i++)
    {
        echo "<p>$desc[$i]</p>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$desc1 = 123;
$desc2 = "asdf";
$desc3 = "asdf123";

for($i = 1; $i<= 3; $i++) {
    echo "<p>" . ${'desc' . $i } ."</p>";
}
```

which outputs:

```
<p>123</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf123</p>
```

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score -1):

What about making them an array of values

```
$desc = Array( 123, "asdf", "asdf123");

for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($desc); $i++) 
  echo "<p>${desc[$i]}</p>";
```